# Conditional statement in java8 forEach loop

Tags: java, java-8

I have string which contain  number of department separated by  comma.
I have to  feed this data to sql 'IN' clause.

I want conditional check for last element, I do not want to append 'comma' after 
last element. I don`t know how to use condition inside java 8 forEach loop.

```
public String  getDeptInClauseParameters(String depts){
       StringBuilder deptsInParameter= new StringBuilder();
       Stream<String>  stream= Arrays.stream(depts.split(","));
       stream.forEach(dept ->  deptsInParameter.append("'").append(dept).append("' , "));
        return deptsInParameter.toString();
    }
```

Comment: You're looking for the part with a Stream, with `.collect(Collectors.joining(", "));`.

Comment: what about  stream.map(dept ->dept= "'"+dept+"' , " );

Comment: @ASdi I don`t want comma  after  last element

Comment: And the usual advice: try to think beyond `forEach`, as otherwise, Streams will never be an improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Collectors.joining(delimiter, prefix, suffix)`.

- `delimiter` the delimiter to be used between each element
- `prefix` the sequence of characters to be used at the beginning of the joined result
- `suffix` the sequence of characters to be used at the end of the joined result

**Example:-**

```
    String depts = "Dept1,Dept2";
    Stream<String> stream = Arrays.stream(depts.split(","));

    System.out.println(stream.collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'")));
```

This will print `'Dept1','Dept2'`as output, hope it helps